# API key for multiple domain script, google map V2

Tags: php, google-maps-api-2

could any one check why my script below is not working please?

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=
<?php  
$this->googleMapsApiKey = $this->getValueFromDB("google", "googleMapsApiKey");
            if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='www.ABC.info') { 
        $this->googleMapsApiKey = "Googlemap-keys";
            } elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='www.CBA.com') { 
        $this->googleMapsApiKey = "Googlemap-keys";
        } 
?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `echo $this->googleMapsApiKey;` at the end of the PHP script maybe? The key in HTML is now empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this whole problem: Maps API keys now support multiple domains (and you can edit authorised domains at any time). See [Obtaining an API key](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#Obtaining_Key) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Wrikken, it does not seem that you echoed the variable during the process. Maybe this approach would help:

```
            <?php  
            print '<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=';
            $this->googleMapsApiKey = $this->getValueFromDB("google", "googleMapsApiKey");
                      switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
                      {
                     //Specific for a domain, but I think that the default handles it against your DB automatically
                     //case 'www.ABC.info' : $this->googleMapsApiKey = "Googlemap-keys";
                     // break;

                     //Same here
                     // case 'www.CBA.com': $this->googleMapsApiKey = "Googlemap-keys";
                     // break;

                      default: $this->googleMapsApiKey = "Googlemap-keys";
                      }

            echo "$this->googleMapsApiKey type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";  

            ?>
```